# Retrieve multiple prices by price_ids array from stripe using laravel Cashier

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

For some reason, I need to fetch multiple (not all) stripe prices at once. I have an array with price_ids such as:

```
$stripe = Cashier::stripe();

$priceIds = [
    'price_1Ow....'., 
    'price_12lsd...'
];

// do something...
```

How I can fetch those prices? Thanks in advance.

Here's what I tried. But it doesn't work properly.

```php
$stripe = Cashier::stripe();
$prices = $stripe->prices->all(
    [
        'lookup_keys' => $priceIds
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't supported in the Stripe API, you just have to loop through the list and call `$stripe->prices->retrieve()` each one.